# Preserve PROD DMV metadata for offline analysis

Tags: sql-server

1. How do I preserve and migrate a point-in-time state of all metadata from a PROD DB to a TEST copy on another server?

I want to review PROD object exec performance and index usage without straining resources or otherwise impacting the state of the PROD DB.  I'm primarily interested in `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` and `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`, plus the other metadata views views commonly used together with them.

2. In general, do perf/usage DMVs depend on host server properties to calculate results accurately?
3. I struggled to find unambiguous search terms.  What is the correct terminology for describing this *perserve and migrate metadata* task?  I'm not even confident that I'm using the word "metadata" accurately.

Comment: Any reason you can't just `SELECT` from them `INTO` a table on a routine basis (such as through a scheduled SQL Agent Job)? The DMVs are *usually* relatively light to query. If you want the results on another server, you can then export those specific tables, or you can setup a Linked Server from your PROD server so your `SELECT ... INTO` query can push the data to your TEST server.

Comment: Most of the `dm_exec...` and usage stats DMVs exist only in memory. So copying them to a "real" table is the main way to preserve them. Commercial monitoring products are essentially purpose-built & extremely complicated products to do this. I think you'll need to make your question more specific to get a decent/useful answer beyond JD's comment above.

Comment: @J.D., I'm doing a bit of learn-as-I-go, so I was hoping to be able to capture the whole state of things at once.  That way, I can continue to explore the DMVs in relation to other data sets at the same point in time.  
Also, I'm a DB dev for a software consultancy, and we have dozens of deployments of our core product.  I can't go back and set up logging at every customer, and for the most part we don't have durable connections to PROD servers, just remote access.  I don't think your idea is unworkable in a pinch, but I was hoping for an easier way to take a comprehensive snapshot on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store) [might](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/query-store-a-flight-data-recorder-for-your-database/) be the best solution for MSSQL 2016+.  It's still not on-demand, but the built-in reporting and tools definitely meet my use cases (regression, A/B testing, resource monitoring).  Thanks for the comments, guys, I might not have found this without the help!

Comment: The **Query Store** is definitely a useful tool to utilize but is a little different than the **DMVs**. Based on your other comments, it sounds like your goal though is to just get familiar with tools for performance analysis and tuning, in which case the Query Store is a good tool to learn. The [**Execution Plan**](https://www.sqlshack.com/execution-plans-in-sql-server/) is another very helpful tool for analyzing and debugging performance, especially with repeatable cases.

Comment: Yeah, mostly I need a way to discover poor performers in PROD, which vary considerably from one environment to the next, due to different hardware, usage patterns, and sometimes heavy customization\extension of the core product.